# HTML5 Validation for textarea

Tags: html, validation

I am using HTML5 for validation. As given in this URL http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_required
if you submit the form with an space, it will allow the form to be submitted.

I would like to restrict the user if the value is blank or it contains only space.

Thanks

Comment: HTML 5 validation is as per each browser's implementation of the HTML 5 Standard.  If that's how it works, then that's how it works... otherwise, you'll have to use some sort of JavaScript validation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript to remove white spaces

To do this, use this function

```
function removeWhiteSpaces(str) {
    return str.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
```

To validate if blank,

```
function validateField() {
    // Trim the input (remove spaces)
    var input = removeWhiteSpaces(document.getElementById('mytextarea').value);

    // We don't accept any blank form
    if (input == '')
        alert('Invalid input.');
    else
        alert('Valid!');
}
```

HTML code,

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="validateField()" value="Validate" />
```

Try this in www3schools.